# Does it converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the sequence $a_n= \sqrt[n]{1+2^{\cos(n\pi)} }$ converge?

Don't know how to start. I'm trying to use squeeze theorem but don't know how. Any general guidance on how to treat these kinds of sequences? Also if it does converge can I find where?

Comment: hint: $\sqrt[n]{3/2}\le a_n\le \sqrt[n]3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: $\sqrt[n]{c}\to 1$ for all $c>0$

Hint 2: $2^{\cos(n\pi)}\in\{2^{-1},2\}$

Hint 3: If $b_n\leq a_n\leq c_n$ and $b_n\to a$ and $c_n\to a$, then $a_n\to a$.

**Solution:**

> Using hint 2, you get $a_n\geq \sqrt[n]{1+2^{-1}}=\sqrt[n]{\frac32}=:b_n$ and $a_n\leq \sqrt[n]{1+2}=\sqrt[n]{3}=:c_n$. From hint 1 you get $b_n\to 1$ and $c_n\to 1$. Finally, hint 3 yields $a_n\to 1$.

Comment: thanks got it !!

Comment: what about the $logn*sin(1/n)$

Comment: That is another question and the argument a little bit more tricky. Hint: Consider that for all $c>0$ holds $\ln(n)\leq cn$ if $n$ is large enough. Try it yourself and if you stuck than you could open a new question for that. But include your attempt!

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any positive integer $n$, $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$ and
$$1\leftarrow\exp\left(\frac{\ln(3/2)}{n}\right)=\sqrt[n]{3/2} \leq \sqrt[n]{1+2^{\cos(n\pi)} }\leq \sqrt[n]{3}=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(3)}{n}\right)\rightarrow 1.$$

P.S. If you replace $1+2^{\cos(n\pi)}$ with any sequence $x_n$ such that $0<a\leq x_n\leq b$ then the result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The subsequences $(a_{2n})$ and  $(a_{2n-1})$ are both convergent with limit $1$. Hence $a_n \to 1$.